# Apache Ignite for long running and large size batch processing

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, batch-processing, ignite

I have some related to long running and large size batch processing questions and interested in real experience and numbers.

First. Am I right, that fault tolerance for long runnig tasks is considered to be handled mostly manually via checkpoints? Let long running tasks here be ones running 1 day or more. Hence, for long running tasks their re-execution may be unappropriate.

Second. Are there any numbers, benchmarks or real experience of processing large data sets which don't fit in memory with Ignite? For example, if available memory is 3, 10 or 100 times smaller than data set size.

Finally. If pure Ignite doesn't fit well for such scenarios, are there any numbers or experience using Ignite as accelerator for Hadoop\Spark?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If it's possible, that a node may go down during work, then you should enable native persistence, and all data, that is written to cache, will be written to disk periodically. Here is documentation on Ignite persistence: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/distributed-persistent-store

But you'll have to figure out, how to restore your task by data, that is written to cache.

I couldn't find any data about benchmark results of Ignite. Only for a product, built on top of it, i.e. GridGain: https://www.gridgain.com/resources/benchmarks/gridgain-benchmarks-results

You can configure persistence for Ignite and run benchmarks yourself. A lot of benchmarks are available in Ignite repository. You can find them in yardstick module on GitHub: https://github.com/apache/ignite/tree/master/modules/yardstick/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/yardstick/cache

Here is documentation on benchmarking: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/perfomance-benchmarking